# how to create header/body validation filters in c# webapi

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, webapp2, wcf-web-api

I am passed the request with post method. I want to validate the request(header/body) using filters. how I can configure the thing using Web api.
 below are my request :

```
x-ln-request:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:requestToken xmlns:ns2="http://services.lexisnexis.com/xmlschema/request-token/1"><transactionID>2886f786-bd20-4220-932b-1bca1a9f7710</transactionID><sequence>1.2.2.2</sequence><contextualFeaturePermID>1000516</contextualFeaturePermID><featurePermID></featurePermID><billBackString descriptionPermId="">-None-</billBackString><isMandatoryBillbackEnforced>false</isMandatoryBillbackEnforced><cpmFeatureCode>47</cpmFeatureCode></ns2:requestToken>
x-ln-session:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns2:sessionToken xmlns:ns2="http://services.lexisnexis.com/xmlschema/session-token/1"><sessionID>c2e9d6f8-6505-4f59-a453-0f7014e58832</sessionID><issued>2014-03-24T02:59:31.484-04:00</issued><userPermIDUrn>urn:user:CA148686</userPermIDUrn><authorizationPermID>1000202</authorizationPermID><signature>v1-ffa9cbc5d0c27c7a36e1a2698fb11189</signature></ns2:sessionToken>
x-ln-i18n:
x-ln-retrieveoptions:
x-ln-application:
```

Body is :

```
<ns3:renderJob xmlns:ns2="http://services.lexisnexis.com/xmlschemas/linktemplate/1" xmlns:ns3="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/renderer/3" xmlns:ns4="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/coredataitem/2" xmlns:ns5="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/subdataitem/2" xmlns:ns6="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/clientmatter/1" xmlns:ns7="http://services.lexisnexis.com/shared/xmlschema/servicescommon/2>
```

How to call filters in webapi, can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

The validation can be performed broadly in two ways 1. Using filters 2. Global handlers
You can check this below link for Filters
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=927

1. Using Global hanlders

Add a new class and use the below code

```
class SampleHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public SampleHandler ()
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //TODO: Validation goes here

        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //_writer.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", request.RequestUri,
              //  (int)response.StatusCode, response.Headers.Date);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

}

Add this line in WebApiConfi file

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new SampleHandler());
```

Reference:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api
https://brettedotnet.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/asp-net-web-api-validation-a-one-more-better-approach/

I hope this will help you